# Calculate time between two datetime angular

Tags: angularjs, datetime, ionic-framework

I have two datetimes which are sent by server and I want to calculate time duration difference in and IONIC App.

I tried to do it but I didn't succeed.

```
"created_date": "2017-04-13 10:12:12",

"current_time": "2017-04-13 11:10:46"
```

Difference= current_time - created_date

Please, help me.

Comment: dates of string type or date?

Comment: @Sajeetharan in string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This working code will help you.

```js
    var inputJSON = {
        "created_date": "2017-04-13 10:12:12",
        "current_time": "2017-04-13 11:10:46"
    };

    function getDataDiff(startDate, endDate) {
        var diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
        var days = Math.floor(diff / (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000));
        var hours = Math.floor(diff / (60 * 60 * 1000)) - (days * 24);
        var minutes = Math.floor(diff / (60 * 1000)) - ((days * 24 * 60) + (hours * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor(diff / 1000) - ((days * 24 * 60 * 60) + (hours * 60 * 60) + (minutes * 60));
        return { day: days, hour: hours, minute: minutes, second: seconds };
    }
    var diff = getDataDiff(new Date(inputJSON.created_date), new Date(inputJSON.current_time));
    console.log(diff);
```